# Framework7 blocks jQuery.appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-framework-7

I use Framework7 and want to use jQuery.appear to run a script when an element gets visible to the user. This works great with this code in a plain HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/morr/jquery.appear/master/jquery.appear.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="update.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <img align="center" id="UpdateIMG1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/Incandescent_light_bulb.svg/200px-Incandescent_light_bulb.svg.png" style="height:10vh">
  </body>
</html>
```

Update.js

```
<!-- Update on first start -->
$.force_appear();
$(function() {
    $("[id^='UpdateIMG']").appear();
    $(".page-content").on('appear', "[id^='UpdateIMG']", function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
        alert("appeared");

    });
    <!--Cancel when element is invisible-->
    $(".page-content").on('disappear', "[id^='UpdateIMG']", function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
        alert("disappeared");
    });
});
```

When I add this to Framework7 (Framework7-1.5.0\examples\inline-pages) appear works **but disappear doesn't**. Why could this be?

https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/archive/v1.5.0.zip

Comment: "doesn't work anymore": no JavaScript errors (see F12 tools)?

Comment: No errors are showing up.

Comment: What is the order of the script-tags when adding Framework7?

Comment: framework7.min.js, jquery.js, jquery.appear.js, update.js, my-app.js - I supsect that $(document.body) could be the problem, but $(".page-content") didn't help either.

Comment: I have edited the question. Disappear is the only thing that doesn't work.

Comment: I can't see framework7 js in your example. And second you are searching for `.page-content` that is missing in your page html.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to capture page loading and unloading using default page class 'page-content'. But it is not good practise when it comes to Framework7. Framework7 has provided many events to capture different phases of page.

Below are set of page events as per Framework7 documentations.

[image]

You can find more details on how to write functions and etc on https://framework7.io/docs/page.html#page-events